# Install phpize on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, php

I wanted to know if there was a way of installing only `phpize`. I've installed it by executing `sudo apt-get install php5-dev`.

I wanted to know if there was a way to just install `phpize` only.

Answer (score 4):

The `php5-dev` package contains various files absolutely essential to compiling PHP. Since it's a shell script, you can just copy it from the package, but it won't work without the dependencies for building a PHP extensions (like header files).

**Explanation**

In the C world, compiling [dynamically linked libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) (DLL/SO) is done by using header files that contain the description on how the libraries are to be interacted with (function calls, structures, etc). These are used to compile an extension without the need for the PHP source code itself. In other words, you don't need the PHP source but you actually need the header files which are contained in `php5-dev`.